# How to automatically insert a decimal place on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I know this has been asked a few times in the past but everything I try is failing. I have a custom numeric keypad with a UILabel. When I hit the '1' the UILabel displays a one. Now here's what I'm trying to do:

- When I hit the '1' button I want: 0.01 in the UILabel
- Followed by a '4' button I want: 0.14 in the UILabel
- Then a '6': 1.46
- etc, etc.

Now the keyboard and UILabel are working great. I just need to get the decimal's working now. Any sample code would be great, (and where I should place it in my application). Let me know if you want to see my code thus far. Pretty straightforward. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Here's about how I would do it:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_DECIMAL_PLACES 2
NSMutableArray *typedNumbers = ...; //this should be an ivar
double displayedNumber = 0.0f; //this should also be an ivar

//when the user types a number...
int typedNumber = ...; //the number typed by the user
[typedNumbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:typedNumber]];
displayedNumber *= 10.0f;
displayedNumber += (typedNumber * 1e-NUMBER_OF_DECIMAL_PLACES);
//show "displayedNumber" in your label with an NSNumberFormatter

//when the user hits the delete button:
int numberToDelete = [[typedNumbers lastObject] intValue];
[typedNumbers removeLastObject];
displayedNumber -= (numberToDelete * 1e-NUMBER_OF_DECIMAL_PLACES);
displayedNumber /= 10.0f;
//show "displayedNumber" in your label with an NSNumberFormatter
```

Typed in a browser.  Caveat Implementor.  Bonus points for using `NSDecimal` instead of a `double`.

Explanation of what's going on:

We're essentially doing bit shifting, but in base 10 instead of base 2.  When the user types a number (ex: 6), we "shift" the existing number left one decimal place (ex: 0.000 => 00.00), multiply the typed number by 0.01 (6 => 0.06), and add that to our existing number (00.00 => 00.06).  When the user types in another number (ex: 1), we do the same thing.  Shift left (00.06 => 00.60), multiply the typed number by 0.01 (1 => 0.01), and add (00.60 => 00.61).  The purpose of storing the number is an `NSMutableArray` is simply a convenience to make deletion easier.  It's not necessary, however.  Just a convenience.

When the user hits the delete button (if there is one), we take the last number entered (ex: 1), multiply it be 0.01 (1 => 0.01), subtract it from our number (0.61 => 0.6), and then shift our number right one decimal place (0.6 => 0.06).  Repeat this as long as you've got numbers in your array of entered numbers.  Disable the delete button when that array is empty.

The suggestion to use `NSDecimal` is simply to allow for very high precision numbers.

Comment: Okay, sorry for all the questions, but I'm building my first application and I'm still very new to objective-c. Could you explain briefly what your code is doing? I know you commented it very well but I'm still unsure of how to use this code :)